# XPages - filtering documents with a Dojo Data Grid

Tags: xpages, dojox.grid, dojo

I'm using a Dojo Data Grid and would like to filter the documents shown using the categoryFilter of the REST service which supplies the data to the Dojo Data Grid. The REST service gets it's data from an xe:viewItemFileService and a Notes View. However, when I add a categorized column as a column in the Notes View, I get an error and no data is displayed. This happens regardless of whether or not any value is added to the categoryFilter of the REST service. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tony, I encountered this as well.   Instead of the category filter use the "keys" to narrow the grid by category.   I wrote this blog post a while back where I encounter the very same issue when using the viewItemFileService.  http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/07/creating-updatable-rest-service-for-use.html

I would consider using the json service instead with your REST, as I found it more reliable.

This question might also help you: [XPages Dojo Data Grid and REST -- can you point to another application's view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238641/xpages-dojo-data-grid-and-rest-can-you-point-to-another-applications-view)

Comment: Steve, thanks a lot. That works great. I did not use a categorized column, just the "key" property and that gave the desired result. I normally prefer to use the viewItemFileService so that columns can be sorted but in this case filtering the view is more important!